# Why my _getch() is not working correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Firstly sorry for my English.
I was trying to make a console game. At the end of the game I wanted to let user choose to continue game or not by selecting yes or no by using arrow keys on keyboard. But it working weirdly right now.  When I pressed the arrow key, the cursor should move but it does it only for a bit and back to selecting "yes". I just really couldn't figure out what is going on here so I wanted to ask somebody who know why is this happening. Please teach me what am I doing wrong.
Thank you.

```
void askForRestart() {
bool yesOrNo = true;

system("cls");
cout << "You died." << endl;
cout << "Restart?" << endl;
cout << "> YES" << endl << "  NO";
while (true) {
    int arrowKeycode = 0;




    switch (arrowKeycode = _getch()) {
    case KEY_ENTER:
        break;
    default:
        if (yesOrNo) {
            yesOrNo = false;
            system("cls");
            cout << "You died." << endl;
            cout << "Restart?" << endl;
            cout << "  YES" << endl << "> NO";
            break;
        }
        else {
            yesOrNo = true;
            system("cls");
            cout << "You died." << endl;
            cout << "Restart?" << endl;
            cout << "> YES" << endl << "  NO";
            break;
        }


    }
    cin.clear();
    //cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because this is how it works. For ordinary character keys (numeric, alphabetic) it returns the key code. But if you tap arrow or functional key, _getch returns 0, which indicates that you must call _getch again to obtain the actual key code.

MSDN:

> When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code.

So you should change your key reading procedure.

Comment: Yes I actually defined keycode for enter key on above. So what I'm trying to do is if the getch returns not a key from enter keycode, ask again. But it just goes back to yes without going into the getch for second loop.